# What tracking_specs to use for boosting facebook/instagram post when calling Ads API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have tried using tracking_set as {"action.type":["post_engagement"], "post":["POST_ID"], "page":["PAGE_ID"]} .

Gets the error even after giving correct values:
{
"error": {
"message": "Invalid parameter",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 1634019,
"is_transient": false,
"error_user_title": "The id of the object (post, page, etc) passed in is invalid.",
"error_user_msg": "Please check that a valid and non-empty object id is passed in.",
"fbtrace_id": "ACSJXbCOwfrANEp9Yz14KKq"
}
}

Any clear documentation available?
How to solve this?

Thank You.